# What do alternating plus and minus operators do?

Tags: c, math, operators

For some reason, this program compiles in C:

```
int x;
x = 3+-+-5+-5;
printf("%d\n",x);
```

And in general, alternating "+" and "-" compiles. It seems like if there are odd "-" then it'll subtract, otherwise, add.

What in the world is this?

Comment: Do you know what unary "minus" does in "normal" math, like `-5`? It does the same in C. An unary "plus" is basically the same, but the opposite (i..e `+5` is equal to plain `5`).

Comment: Arithmetic.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases such as these, the first + or - to the right of the left-hand operand indicates the binary operation to perform; the other + and - after that are the unary + and - operators applied to the right-hand operand. The unary + operand does nothing and - changes the sign. This gives rise to the behavior you see: an odd number of - is either addition of a negative quantity (+ followed by +s and an odd number of -s) or subtraction of a positive quantity (- followed by +s and an even number of -s).

Comment: Hmm, I see. Why don't two '+' in a row compile then, like 4++5?

Comment: @Lokwill: I believe because it gets parsed as `(4++) 5`, with the postincrement `++` operator.  You see that *postfix-expression* comes before *unary-operator cast-expression* in the grammar rule for *unary-expression* in 6.5.3 of the standard.  You'd have to write `4+(+5)` or `4+ +5`.

Comment: Good point, two ++ in a row right after or before a variable probably get interpreted like the increment operators. I imagine ++ with - on either side might work though... since the increment operators are not valid in that context it might fall back.